# Darken image in the background

Tags: css

Is there any way to darken a `.png` image? I have one as a background image, but it does not cover the whole container, if I set overlay to darken it.

```
.overlay {
    background-color: #322D36 ;
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0;
     opacity: 0.5;
     position: absolute;
     right: 0;
     top: 0;
     z-index: 1;
}
```

It's also visible outside of the image space. Is there any way how to darken only image?

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cyofy254/)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the (not super supported) `filter` property like so.

```
filter: brightness(0.4);
```

Some prefixes such as `-webkit-` may be needed.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cyofy254/1/).

EDIT because of comment:

Make the container the width and height of your image, then add the image using the before pseudo class.

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: ###;
  height: ###;
}

.container:before {
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background-image: some-url;
  -webkit-filter: brightness(0.4);
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Put all your text in the `.content` div.

Comment: What if the container also has a tex in it ? It would darken the text too and ruin its color.

Comment: But in your case the content inside will be always dark. Look it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyofy254/5/)

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `linear-gradient` to your background.

```
background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) ), url("https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-kDFp715GK_iC4AwrDWQpCR0HfxDMp0WYZATcnlXDhXgf-05OTv3Z9E-P1bL2imdAFAtWg=w1876-h815");
```

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cyofy254/3/).

Here another [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cyofy254/4/) in which you can see that only the background will be dark and the rest of elements will be normal.

Comment: Yes , but as i said i need only image to be dark. This demo shows that the remaining space of container which isnt covered by image will be dark too.

Comment: @Josh No, it is not. It is white space where the image does not cover.

Comment: @Josh Oh wait, have you changed the img? Also, look the second example.

Comment: No i did not change img. If you notice the bottom of image is triangle shaped which leave space of container uncovered. Using this it change color from white (defualt ) to the linear gradiend.

Comment: @Josh I am sorry but I do not see the triangle shaped. One thing that I do not understand very well is why in the first example the white-space it is being affected by the linear-gradient and in the second one it does not.

Answer (score 0):

you can using background-color after `background-image` property, and using **`background-blend-mode`** property for overlay the `background-image`. Here is the example

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PQOejG?editors=1100